# Rails Associations: Access Foreign Value Through Non-Standard Name

Tags: ruby, associations, ruby-on-rails-3

I had to break the Rails convention in order to satisfy a business need and it's causing me some pain. My intention is to be able to reference a foreign table (through Rails) through two separate methods.

In a typical scenario, you'd have something like this:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees
end
```

You could then reference a company, through an Employee object doing something like the following:

```
e = Employee.find(1)
puts e.company.name
```

That works fine for most tables, but say we have a table like the following:

```
id - integer
default_channel_id - integer and foreign key reference to channel table
selected_channel_id - integer and foreign key reference to channel table
```

As depicted, it's not possible to simply allow the convention to determine how the association is made because more than one column references the same foreign key value.

I've been reading the [Rails documentation on associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to), but I haven't found anything that allows me to define associations in this way. The closest I got was through the :foreign_key option, but that alone didn't work because it created a single method with the name channel. Following is my attempt:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :channel, :foreign_key => "default_channel_id"
  belongs_to :channel, :foreign_key => "selected_channel_id"
end
```

How should I go about this?

**Note:** Just in case it helps, I'm working with Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the associations like this:

```
belongs_to :default_channel, :class_name => "Channel"
belongs_to :selected_channel, :class_name => "Channel"
```

This will reference the `default_channel_id` field in your database to load the `default_channel` association when you request it and I bet with that information you can work out what happens when you call `selected_channel`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :default_channel, :class_name => "Channel"
  belongs_to :selected_channel, :class_name => "Channel"
end
```

and

```
class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :default_channels, :foreign_key => 'default_channel_id'
  has_many :selected_channels, :foreign_key => 'selected_channel_id'
end
```